# How to copy files from some source path with gradle script?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to copy images for javadocs with gradle. Currenly images are located under

```
MYPROJECT/src/main/resources/doc-files/images/
```

I refer these images with something like this

```
<img src="{@docRoot}/doc-files/images/myimage.jpg">
```

Now I wish to copy all content from under `MYPROJECT/src/main/resources/doc-files/` into `MYPROJECT/build/docs/javadoc/doc-files/` and I write in `build.gradle`:

```
javadoc << {

    FileTree docFilesTree = fileTree(dir: 'src/main/resources/doc-files')

    copy {
        from docFilesTree
        into destinationDir
    }

}
```

This has two problems:

1) It does nothing :)

2) It refers `resources/doc-files/images/` explicitly, while I would like to deduce it from parameters. I failed to know how to use something from here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: And do you have any sample to try it out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by you want to deduce `resources/doc-files/images` from its parameters.

However, if you want to copy files from one directory to another, you can create a task such as:

```
FileTree docFilesTree = fileTree(dir: 'src/main/resources/doc-files')

task copyJavaDocSupportFiles(type: Copy) {
    from docFilesTree
    into 'build/docs/javadoc/doc-files/'
}
```

You can then add this dependency to a javadoc task such as:

```
task generateJavadocs(type: Javadoc, dependsOn: ['copyJavaDocSupportFiles']) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
}
```

When you run the generateJavadocs task, it will copy the files from `src/main/resources/doc-files` to `build/docs/javadoc/doc-files`